# Load Chinese single word into array

Tags: php, utf-8, ucs2

I have a file with multiple lines of Chinese words separated by comma `,` like this:

```
你，我，他，好，但，中，国，龙
好，把，是，的，啊，人，吖，哦
```

I want to load them to array by using the following code, which will later allow me to use this array to find Chinese words contained in an article:

```
$ds = file($Dictionary);
$_SP_ = chr(0xFF).chr(0xFE);
$array = array();
foreach($ds as $d)
{
    $spstr = _SP_;//
    $spstr = iconv(ucs-2be, 'utf-8', $spstr);
    $ws = explode(',', $d);//array of single Chinese word
    $wall = iconv('utf-8', ucs-2be, join($spstr, $ws));//what is $wall used for?
    $ws = explode(_SP_, $wall);
    foreach($ws as $estr)
    {
        $array[$estr] = strlen($estr);
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. What does `$_SP_ = chr(0xFF).chr(0xFE) mean?chr(0xFF).chr(0xFE)` is a string retrieve from the last two character from ASCII, the combination of this two for what?
2. Why I should convert the *SP* to utf-8 format from ucs-2b?
3. Why `$ws` is again be converted to string but separated by `chr(0xFF).chr(0xFE)` of utf-8 type.
4. Why it needs the length of every single word?
5. Why `$spstr` is of UCS-2be type,only because it is the combination of `chr(0xFF).chr(0xFE)`?

Comment: Answer to #1.... It's a UTF-16LE [BOM marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that indicates the file is UTF-16LE encoded

Comment: the multibyte safe equivalent for explode is mb_split(). And don't miss the mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8') part :-)